# Remove Enter key binding in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, key-bindings

What is the simplest and **fastest way** to remove the standard enter key bindings (pressing enter selects the next row) in a JTable?

That's what I tried

```
table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), null);
```

But it doesn't work. I assume that we have to do that somehow for each cell and not the table itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` and `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` have a value for the enter keystroke. So you want to get both of them</s>

Correction: You need to get the `InputMap` for `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`

```
InputMap iMap1 = 
         table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
//InputMap iMap2 = 
        // table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
```

Then you want to set the value for the map to `"none"`, instead of `null`, as described in [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

> To make a component ignore a key that it normally responds to, you can use the special action name "none". For example, the following code makes a component ignore the F2 key.
>   
>   `component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"), "none");`

So just do:

```
KeyStroke stroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
iMap1.put(stroke, "none");
//iMap2.put(stroke, "none");
```

---

Also note when you just do `getInputMap()` without any arguments, it's basically the same thing as `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED)`. And in the case of `JTable`, there's no value for the enter keystroke for that `InputMap`.

Read more at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). You'll get a better explanation of the different `InputMaps`

---

**UPDATE** : Correction (corrections made above either <s>struck through</s> or `// commented out`)

You only to set it for the `InputMap` for `JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`

---

**UPDATE** per the OP comment: Yes in short

```
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
                             .put(KeyStroke.‌​getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "none");
```

Comment: To summarize it: `table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "none");` does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the most convenient way:

```
table.registerKeyboardAction(
    null,
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0),
    JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT
);
```

To assign an action replace `null` with `ActionListener` call or with `e -> someMethod()` for JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Update:
David Kroukamp solution:

```
private void createKeybindings(JTable table) {
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Enter");
    table.getActionMap().put("Enter", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {}
    });
}
```

And for you should be enough:

```
table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Enter");
table.getActionMap().put("Enter",null);
```

I dont know if it is possible to use `null`, you could use anonymous class instead...

Comment: Try `Action` instead of `Input`

Comment: there is maybe yours solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516730/disable-enter-key-from-moving-down-a-row-in-jtable